# I try to build Follow system, I have error when i try to get the pk of the vested account

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I try to build follow system in Django, My code Filed when I try to get the pk of the current vested account which I try follow them

The Error message
NoReverseMatch at /account/3/ Reverse for 'add-follower' with keyword arguments '{'pk': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['account/follower/(?P[0-9]+)/add$']

my models

```
class Account(AbstractBaseUser):
email = models.EmailField(verbose_name="email", max_length=60, unique=True)
username = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
following = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, blank=True, related_name="follow")
```

My views

```
class AddFollwers(LoginRequiredMixin, View):
def post(self, request, pk, *args, **kwargs):
    account = Account.objects.get(pk=pk)
    account.following.add(request.user)
    return redirect('account', pk=account.pk)
```

The urls

```
urlpatterns = [
path('<int:user_id>/', account_view, name="view"),
path('follower/<int:pk>/add', AddFollwers.as_view(), name='add-follower'),]
```

The Template

```
<form action="{% url 'account:add-follower' pk=pk%}" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Follow</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Exactly where do you use this template? What do you pass to the template?

Comment: @Willem Van Onsem
 I use this template (account.html) in the same models and views app and I passed to this template  `     context['id'] = account.id
        context['username'] = account.username
        context['email'] = account.email
        context['profile_image'] = account.profile_image.url
        context['hide_email'] = account.hide_email
        context['bio'] = account.bio
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You passed the primary key of the account as `id`, not `pk`, so you use this in the url as:

```
<form action="{% url 'account:add-follower' pk=id %}" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Follow</button>
</form>
```

Furthermore, the name of your `account_view`  is `view`, which does not make much sense, you can rename it to `account`:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('<int:user_id>/', account_view, name='account'),
    path('follower/<int:pk>/add', AddFollwers.as_view(), name='add-follower')
]
```

Since you specified an `app_name` in your views, you need to prefix the view name with the `app_name`, so:

```
class AddFollwers(LoginRequiredMixin, View):
    
    def post(self, request, pk, *args, **kwargs):
        account = Account.objects.get(pk=pk)
        account.following.add(request.user)
        return redirect('account:account', pk=account.pk)
```

Comment: Thank you That's solved my problem but unfortunately there is another problem appeared   
 `NoReverseMatch at /account/follower/3/add
Reverse for 'account' not found. 'account' is not a valid view function or pattern name.`

Comment: @MohamedSoliman: you need to change the name of your view to `account`, since you use `return redirect('account', account.pk)`. Since you named your view `name='view'` that this will not work. This was already mentioned in the answer.

Comment: I renamed but still have the same problem

Comment: @MohamedSoliman: did you use an `app_name` in your `urls.py`?

Comment: Yes `app_name = 'account'`

Comment: @WillemVanOnsemThank you very much you are life saver ,I had stuck In this problem for week